# setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "de_DE.UTF8") or setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "de_DE.UTF-8")?

Tags: php, utf-8, locale

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "de_DE.UTF8")
```

or

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "de_DE.UTF-8")
```

With or without dash?  I've seen both in answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd run `locale -a` and use the string it outputs. On OS X 10.9, I get `de_DE.UTF-8`. On Debian 6, I get `de_DE.utf8`. `dpkg-reconfigure locales` uses `de_DE.UTF-8` on the other hand. The safest way is probably to check the return value of `setlocale` and try different variants if it fails.

That said, all versions should usually work: with or without dash, uppercase or lowercase.

Comment: Perfect. I have `Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.9 (squeeze)` and `locale -a` outputs `de_DE.utf8` – among a hundred others.

Comment: @what `locale -a | grep -i de_de` should help.

Answer (score 2):

The name of the encoding is UTF-8.

but in this case both parameters are correct and they are doing same job for you

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pragmatic solution for resolving it programatically. When `setlocale` fails, it returns false.

```
if (!setlocale(LC_ALL, str_replace('utf-8', 'utf8', $locale)) 
 && !setlocale(LC_ALL, str_replace('utf8', 'utf-8', $locale))) {
   /* fail gracefully */
}
/* your locale has been set up properly
```

In my case one would work on our Macs and the other would work on the Linux CI boxes, so this solution makes tests pass on both.

Btw; beware of LC_ALL. Set the locale for the weakest scope you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually pass an array of values to `setLocale()`. I've just run into this problem while developing on OSX and testing at the hosting running on Linux. So now I do this: `setLocale(LC_ALL, ["de.utf", "de_DE.utf", "de_DE.UTF-8", "de", "de_DE"])` The first one to match is a go.
Docs: https://secure.php.net/setlocale